# Estimating two matrix using Hidden markov model toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to apply Hidden Markov Model to improve my detection accuracy.

In my program, there are two states, 1 and 0. I used Bayes detector to generate the probability for each instance to be in class 1 and 0. For example, I have a sequence Actual states: 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
probability in class 1: 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.5 
probability in class 0: 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.5

I tried to "use probability in class 1" as the "seq" and "Actual states" as "states" in function hmmestimate ([estimateTR, estimateE] = hmmestimate(seq,states);)

But it seems that "seq" must be integers, and I do not understand what is the requirement for the input arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question is not very clear, please provide more info

Comment: What you have is the hidden state probabilities and the actual hidden states. What hmmestimate does is find the transition and emission probabilities given the actual hidden states and the observed (non-hidden) sequence of symbols.